# remove red border color from iphone lay out

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

when you reduce the browser window you will see a red border color..
I am trying to remove the red border around the div.
I tried removing the border color but its not going....
how to fix it providing my code below...

http://jsfiddle.net/CAARt/embedded/result/

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
#gallery {
display: inherit !important;
border: 1px solid red;
width: 417px;
}

<div id="gallery">
            <div class="pagination-centered" style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">Main Menu</div>

            <div id="slider" style="overflow: hidden; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
                <ul style="list-style: none; margin: 0px; width: 1440px; -webkit-transition: 300ms; ">
```

Comment: I cannot see a border, but try `outline:none;`

Comment: I see you have border defined for width less than 767, so why not just remove that line???

Comment: even wehn i remove it in firebug its not working

Comment: works for me, have you tried removing it? or did you only try removing it in firebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following, tried in firebug and works

```
border: 1px solid red;
```